# Is it possible to add another level of keys iteratively to a dictionary to generate a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

So my idea is to kind of generate a dictionary in such a way:

```
my_dict = {}

for x in range(len(something)):
   for y in range(len(something_else)):
        my_dict[x] = {}
        my_dict[x][y] = {key: value}
```

However, when I try doing it like this, I always end up getting the error message:

KeyError: 0 or KeyError: '0' if I use strings instead of integers.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: That code won't give that error. Is it when you use the dictionary later? You replace `my_dict[x]` with an empty dictionary on every loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing what your are doing you "erase" `my_dict[x]` on each `y` loop.

Try:

```py
my_dict = {}

for x in range(len(something)):
   for y in range(len(something_else)):
        d = my_dict.setdefault(x, {})
        d[y] = {key: value}
```

Or:

```py
my_dict = {}

for x in range(len(something)):
    my_dict[x] = {}
    for y in range(len(something_else)):
        my_dict[x][y] = {}
        for z in range(len(other)):
            my_dict[x][y][z] = {key: value}
```

Comment: Ok and how would I proceed if I have 3 for loops? Would it be something like this: ```d = my_dict.setdefault(x, {})
        d[y][z] = {key: value}```

Comment: What you have to remember is you can either initialize the the "node" dict one step before the loop you'll use it (juste afer the first for loop you initialize level 1 with empty dict) or use setdefault to prevent writing over something existing but giving a default value if not.

Comment: But how would I initialize the node dict before the loop if I still want it to be iterated through in the for loop. I'm assuming, that for the first one, it would look something like ```my_dict[x] = {}``` or am I mistaking?

Comment: This seems brittle and won't generalize to an unknown level of nesting (think recursion)

Comment: Obviously you know that considering recursion is not the same than considering loops right? If you want an unknown level of nesting by recursion use recursion.

Comment: Any looping solution can be represented by recursion, so no they are not the same but they are similar. Also, that still doesn't change the fact that this is brittle. Just FYI

Answer (score 2):

You can create an arbitrarily nested dictionary with ease using [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

make_dict = lambda: defaultdict(make_dict)
my_dict = make_dict()
```

```
my_dict[1][2][3] = 4  # wrap this inside a nested loop as deep as you like
my_dict

defaultdict(<function __main__.<lambda>()>,
            {1: defaultdict(<function __main__.<lambda>()>,
                         {2: defaultdict(<function __main__.<lambda>()>,
                                      {3: 4})})})
```

Comment: I always like this surprisingly simple solution. I would name the function `make_tree` or even `Tree`, and define it as a function rather than a lambda.

Comment: @PeterWood how would you go about doing that?

Comment: @Omar Doing what? Defining it as a function? `def make_dict(): return defaultdict(make_dict)`